# Log Elmah Errors in SQL Server using ASP.NET Core API 2.1

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, elmah

I configure ELMAH to log all errors in my Api. It's working and I can see the logs by accessing https://app.elmah.io.

I'm using ASP.NET Core Web API 2.1 so it doesn't have a `web.config`.

The problem is: how can I log the error in my SQL Server database?

**PRINTS:**

[My class StartUp.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZmiC.png)

[My AppSettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXnCF.png)

Answer (score 1):

ELMAH and elmah.io are two different things. Of the two, only elmah.io supports ASP.NET Core. More details here: [ELMAH and elmah.io differences](https://docs.elmah.io/elmah-and-elmah-io-differences/).

There is a port of ELMAH for ASP.NET Core available here: https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore. If you are looking to self host your logs, it sounds like you should look into ElmahCore instead of elmah.io.

Comment: I was using the ElmahCore with Windows authentication and it worked well for me. However, I have to move to Anonymous Authentication in IIS along with token based authentication on front end and Elmah has stopped logging the user name in Elmah_Error table. Any idea on how to deal with that?

Comment: Hi Ravi. Maybe I am missing something, but your question sounds like a completely different issue. Maybe create a new question?